# .jsproj cannot be opened. This project type is not supported by this installation

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova, visual-studio-templates

I am trying to create a new project in VS2015 community edition using JavaScript template but getting error:

> The project file 'IonicCordovaProjectSolution\IonicCordovaProject\IonicCordovaProject.jsproj' cannot be opened. This project type is not supported by this installation"

Do I need to install anything else to make JavaScript templates work?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To make .jsproj work, HTML/JavaScript component must be selected while installing VS. For my case, I had selected typical installation so it didn't give option to select components to be installed and HTML/JavaScript component was not installed by default. Choose a custom installation and select `Cross Platform Mobile Development > HTML/JavaScript`

Re-execuate exe, select modify option and install HTML/JavaScript component, if you have already installed visual studio 2015 with typical installation.

Comment: You can change the installation option via "programs and features", select visual studio 2015 and click "change"

Comment: @sanjeev : It takes too much time for me and downloaded almost 10Gb is it ok ?

Comment: @sanjeev Thanks for finding this! VS is making me go insane.

Comment: @MicahWilliamson I am glad it helped :)

Comment: Almost 10Gb is it ok ? For what? I have already Android SDK. And I must place it again and again?

Comment: @SiarheiAArlou I guess it does download all components again.

Comment: @sanjeev, any one having this issue with VS2017?

Comment: @IbrarMumtaz I didn't try VS 2017 yet but I guess if you are experiencing the same issue, then that means you need to do a custom installation and select Cross Platform Mobile Development > HTML/JavaScript or similar option in VS 2017 too.