# Cannot open jsproj files in Visual Studio 2015 Blend (Community Edition)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

According to this post: [Visual Studio 2015: .jsproj cannot be opened. This project type is not supported by this installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32008603/visual-studio-2015-jsproj-cannot-be-opened-this-project-type-is-not-supported) it should be enough to install html/javascript package to Visual Studio 2015, when you install it and then you could open jsproj type of files.

I continue receiving notice of (incompatible) and application is not installed.

Is there something to do with the fact I have a community edition of VS only?

I try to open a cordova cli created project (newest cli) and still the html / javascript says it is for Cordova exactly. Why it then does not work?

Comment: hmm.. I found this to migrate the project so that it would be understood: https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/migrate-to-vs2015/ Have to give a try.

Comment: failing again at line: "create js project from new -> jsproj" because that just not appear in menu.

Comment: As far as I know, Tools for Apache Cordova does not support VS Blend. Please open the cordova app with Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: @Elvis, please mark that as an answer, the trick was to use Visual Studio 2015 instead of Blend. I still use community edition. It was the Blend, not community, that was causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Tools for Apache Cordova does not support VS Blend.

Please open the cordova app with Visual Studio 2015 Community.